# Sharing database connection with an external program

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, wildfly

We have application *Foo* launched inside Web container (WildFly 14). It gets database connection in a standard way, through JNDI. So, connection is configured not inside the application, but in WildFly.

Now, *Foo* launches an external program *Bar* on the same machine. This external program is meant to be fully independent from the main application, but needs access to the very same database. *Bar* is also connected to *Foo* through pipes, so it is not a problem to pass serializable objects from one to another.

With straightforward implementation, I would need to configure *Bar*'s access to the database separately from *Foo*.

Is it somehow possible to automatically pass necessary database connection parameters from *Foo* to *Bar*? Since we use two different types of database, this would include JDBC driver too (*Foo* gets it "for free" from a WildFly deployment). Plus JDBC URL, username and password. Autodetermining even some of these would be helpful.

We control and can change practically everything in this setup (*Foo* and *Bar* source, WildFly configuration).

Comment: Why doesn't your external application also use JNDI to grab the datasource (from Wildfly server) ?

      DataSource datasource =(DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/demo");

Comment: Because it is run as a separate process and doesn't have access to WildFly.

Comment: Your process, even is separate, just need access to..the network. You app will contain a JNDI client doing a lookup to a remote JNDI server via the network.

Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "<remote-url-here>"");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext( jndiProperties );

Comment: I have very basic understanding of JNDI and brief research shows it is very confusing (to me). Could you maybe write an answer detailing how a process running on the same machine could connect to WildFly over JNDI and retrieve bound objects? E.g. does it need additional libraries etc. (Also, I hope that after establishing connection, process would talk to the database directly, not involving WildFly, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two other alternatives (much more lightweight than JNDI)

1. You could use the **admin REST api** of Wildfly to read the datasource settings defined on the server (in /configuration/standalone-***.xml). Your app can so issue a simple (authenticated) http GET request and parse the obtained xml.

http://localhost:9990/management/subsystem/datasources/data-source/ExampleDS?operation=resource&recursive=true&json.pretty=1

2. Similarly these settings are also exposed by Wildfly in **JMX**. You just have to read them, either using JMX api of the JDK, or one of the numerous opensource libs easying JMX query.
   Just run a "jconsole", connect to the process running you WF server, and look up the attributes of your datasource.
   => locate "ConnectionUrl", "userName" and "password" attributes. Then code your app to read those 3 attributes.

Good luck !

[image]

Comment: Works with one little quirk. If I perform JMX queries "later", when WildFly is already fully initialized, everything is fine. But if I do it while the server is booting up, I get weird behavior: `MBeanServer.queryMBeans(...)` properly returns list of JDBC connection configuration(s), but `MBeanServer.getAttribute()` on them fails with "WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-attribute") failed ... WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\")]' not found". Do you by chance know how to wait until server bootstrap is finished?

Comment: Nevermind, found how to do it too with JMX. Apparently WildFly never sends notifications, at least for changes in `jboss.as:management-root=server`, but I'm fine with polling it once a second.